# How to show image when a specific key is pressed in p5js?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-events

I'm new to p5js :)

When users press a certain key between 1-0 on the keyboard, a certain sound plays and random image shows. I tried this...

```
function keyPressed() {
   if (key === '2') {
        songA.play()
        image(imgB1, random(windowWidth), random(windowHeight), img.width/2, img.height/2); 
   }
```

But p5js only reads "image" in draw function. Then i tried keyisdown in the draw function and tried entering the keyCodes for each number, for instance 1 is 49 I believe, but it didn't work.

```
  if (keyIsDown(49)) {
     songA.play()
     image(imgB1,random(windowWidth), random(windowHeight), img.width/2, img.height/2); 
}}
```

I'm basically copying https://openprocessing.org/sketch/441971 from openprocessing which is similar to p5js but not really. Help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your image is being preloaded in the setup() function
2. When you display the image, you are referencing "img" instead of imgB1, which means p5js doesn't know what size to display the image at, so I assume it defaults to 0. To fix this, just replace img with imgB1.